# executeUpdate method is not working properly

Tags: java, database, prepared-statement

I am using preparedStatement.executeUpdate() for inserting some rows in the database but it's not working. Though when i debug it returns the value as 1 which means the row has been inserted but when i check the database it doesn't insert any rows. Not sure why it is happening. Any kind of help would be appreciated. Below is my code :

```
Connection connection = null;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

try {
    connection = getOracleConnection(requestId);
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(createAndSaveSummarySQL());
    preparedStatement.setString(1, siteId);
    preparedStatement.setString(PBNConstants.TWO, taskId);
    preparedStatement.setString(PBNConstants.THREE, notificationType);
    preparedStatement.setString(PBNConstants.FOUR, clusterId);


    final long insertStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    final int returnValue = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: You use a Cache, you make a rollback after Insertion? How do you check if the row is ínserted? mybe you have different db Connections?

Comment: Please Show the catch .. finally ... block

Comment: please add the exception that you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly make sure connection is closed in proper way like below.

```
 try {
            connection = getOracleConnection(requestId);     

    }finally{
     if (preparedStatement != null) preparedStatement.close();
      if (connection != null) connection.close();
    }
```

Comment: @Jen Hi, thanks for responding back. I am closing the connection properly at the end. One more thing, I am checking the insertion while debugging. So final int returnValue = preparedStatement.executeUpdate(); returns a value of 1 while debugging but just after that when i check the database i don't see any row getting inserted. The strange thing is immediately i inspect this statement and it gives me an error which says "SQL Unique integrity constraint violation" so believe a row gets inserted but i don't see it.
A bit of strange behavior i am seeing but not getting to any conclusion

Comment: if (connection != null) {
   try {
    connection.close();
   } catch (final SQLException e) {
    
   }
  }

Comment: @Rohit - I don't get any exception. It's just that the row does not gets inserted and my application fails because after insertion i update that row based on the header_id and it fails during update because it does not find any row to be updated.